# stylePreprocessorOptions includePaths is not importing my scss files

Tags: angular, angular-workspace-configuration

I have started using Angular multi-projects workspace. So I created a `style` folder which contains all my shared scss files.

In the `angular.json` file, for each project I have added the following in the architect/build/options section:

```
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "styles"
          ]
        }
```

but when I run `ng build my-project` or `ng serve my-project` the main.scss file under `styles` folder is not included.

This file basically imports all the scss files that are in the subfolders under `styles´ like this

```
 @import "base/base";
 @import "base/typography";
 @import "base/helpers";
 @import "base/fonts";
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: By "not included", you mean that if you do `@import 'main'`, nothing happens? That's weird. Your setup seems to be ok.

Comment: duh ! I forgot to do the import in each app's style.scss file !  I dumbly thought that including the path was enough... Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this issue in **Angular14**. Earlier I had been using a relative path for importing global SCSS files (using '~' sign). But latest version of Angular stopped using this sign and also it started using DartSCSS. Till now, it seems that **Angular14** has not been supporting **stylePreprocessorOptions** in its **angular.json** file. [github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25047) has also no clue on this issue. So, as of now I have removed **stylePreprocessorOptions** from **angular.json** and added path as "`@import './src/styles/global-mixins` This resolves two issues-

1. I don't need to use **~** sign anymore.
2. **No** need to add a relative path like `../../../styles/global-mixins`

In future, if I get some solution to this problem I will update here.

Comment: This is very strange. 1. stylePreprocessorOptions worked for me in Angular 14. But it stopped to work when I upgraded to Angular 16, and I can't find why. 2. I was, frankly, skeptical about your solution, as it seems not to make sense logically speaking. But… it works! So it is good enough for me. Thanks.